# FFmpegのhevc_nvencの圧縮率について

Tags: ffmpeg

Macで収録した`.mov`をWindowsもしくはWSL2で長期保存用のなにかしらにエンコードするのが差し当たっての目標です．

次のような引数の構成で`.mov`を`.mp4`に変換します：

```
ffmpeg -to 01:07:10 -i input.mov \
    -vcodec hevc_nvenc -r 30 -vf crop=1116:1600:720:0 output.mp4
```

出力ファイルのサイズ：

- `-vcodec hevc_nvenc`をつけると667.8 MB
- `-vcodec h264_nvenc`をつけると604.1 MB
- `-vcodec`をつけないと245.8 MB

H.264を用いた方がH.265よりサイズが小さくなるのは異常に思えますし，NVEncに関連するパラメータを用いるとファイルサイズが大きくなるのは直感に反します．
GPUを使うメリットってなんですか？
GPUを使うと多少処理が速くなりますがこれではデメリットの方が大きく感じます．
ハードウェアエンコードってこういうものですか？
根本から間違えている気がします．

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[結局ハードウェアエンコードってどうなの？(H265篇)](https://qiita.com/yamakenjp/items/6a37afef25b1e4254669)という記事がありました。
この記事では

- X264（X265？）によるソフトウェアエンコード
- Intel HD 630を使ったIntelQSV
- NVIDIA T400をつかったNVENC

を比較し、VMAFによる動画の品質を評価するツールで検証しています。まとめから引用しますと

> 改めてx265とQSV、NVEncを比較しましたが、単純にビットレートやqP指定でのエンコードの場合、HWエンコーダの特性を考えて最適な値にしないと、ただ早くて画質は悪いという状況になるため、パラメータの調整が必須というのがよくわかったのと、VMAFにて客観的な比較ができるため、VMAFの値を参考にチューニングをする必要がある。

とのことです。詳細は記事を参照ください。

長期保存目的であれば、x265などソフトウェアエンコードの方が適切かもしれません。

Comment: その記事で未検証だった「Bフレーム圧縮」を試したら584 MBまで小さくできました．

Comment: 今回の用途ではソフトウェアエンコードを採用しようと思います．一応Bフレームの引数を入れたものを書いておきます．`ffmpeg -hwaccel cuda -y -to 01:07:10 -i input.mov -vcodec hevc_nvenc -refs 5 -bf 3 -b_ref_mode each -tag:v hvc1 -r 30 -vf crop=1116:1600:720:0 output.mp4` ありがとうございました．